# Oracle Hierarchical Query - Get records in hierarchy where children are in a list

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have a table with Parent, Child relationship. On another table I have a list of members that are leaves in the first table.

What I would like to do is to have the first table filtered by the members which are parents of the member in the second table, or the members of the second table. I hope my problem is clear, if not please ask.

Database is Oracle 10g.

Comment: Please show the table's definitions, and sample data for each table, and expected output, and what you have tried.

Comment: So you want all leafs, and their parents?  What's the second table for?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this hierarchy in table `TH` and in members table `TM` there are three rows 'GC Carl', 'PT Mike', 'PT Mary' (marked green).

[image]

To find  all their parents, grandparents etc. (marked yellow) you need this simple hierarchical query:

```
select distinct id
  from th
  connect by id = prior pid
  start with id in (select id from tm)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce0e1/1)

If you are looking only for parents and you need to do in hierarchical way then:

```
select distinct id
  from th
  connect by id = prior pid and level <= 2
  start with id in (select id from tm)
```

(Martin is eliminated, because he is not parent for any member and he is absent in `TM`).

If this is not what you wanted you should definitely precise your query, add sample input data and desired output.